# Using variables outside the function

Tags: php, function, variables

this is probebly a silly question but I don't know where else to ask this.
I need to call on $conn in the functions below, but if I try to turn it into a global it doesn't work. If someone can explain to me how to use an outside variable inside a function I'd be very grateful.

Here's my little piece of code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 //Maak connectie met database
 $host = "localhost";
 $username = "i266161_studie";
 $password = "studie";
 $dbnaam = "test";
 $fout = "Error: Failed to open database";

 $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbnaam)
 or die ("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error()); 

function insert_once($conn){
$query = 'INSERT INTO gebruikers (naam, leeftijd, woonplaats)
VALUES ("Henk", 17, "Eindhoven")';
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}

function insert_twice($conn){
$query = 'INSERT INTO gebruikers (naam, leeftijd, woonplaats)
VALUES ("Bert", 21, "Helmond"), ("Ruud", 32, "Helmond")';
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
insert_twice();

?>
```

Comment: It's in the manual, in the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section. (hint: `global` keyword or `$GLOBALS` variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use globals unless you REALLY have to! don't forget to pass your `$conn` parameter to your functions e.g.

change this:

```
insert_twice();
```

to this:

```
insert_twice($conn);
```

I'd suggest adding some error handling to your `mysql_query()` calls too, you should not assume that these are always successful

Answer (score 1):

I personally would try 1) to create a connection class that has a static connection (basically a global without being a `global`) that allows you to create instances both inside and outside of functions. Also, if you make it a singleton, you can reuse the same connection without anymore resources 2) Make one function that can handle more than one insert. Below is just an example, use or don't use it, but it will give you a simple example, by no means is it complete, so use at your own risk:

**interface.Database.php**

```
interface   Database
    {   
        public  static  function SetConnection($host,$username,$password,$dbnaam);
    }
```

**class.MySQLConn.php**

```
class   MySQLConn implements Database
    {           
        protected   static  $host;
        protected   static  $username;
        protected   static  $password;
        protected   static  $dbnaam;

        public      static $connect;

        private function __construct()
            {
            }

        public  static  function SetConnection($host = "localhost",$username = "i266161_studie",$password = "studie",$dbnaam = "test")
            {
                self::$host     =   $host;
                self::$username =   $username;
                self::$password =   $password;
                self::$dbnaam   =   $dbnaam;
                self::$connect  =   (!isset(self::$connect))? self::Initialize() : self::$connect;
            }

        private static  function Initialize()
            {
                return new mysqli(self::$host, self::$username, self::$password, self::$dbnaam);
            }
    }
```

**function.insert_into.php**

```
// Make your insert a bit more robust
// Should be built out to accommodate preparing and binding
// This will handle one or multiple row insert
function insert_to($settings = false)
    {
        $con    =   MySQLConn::$connect;

        $table  =   (isset($settings['table']))? $settings['table']:"gebruikers";
        $cols   =   (isset($settings['cols']) && is_array($settings['cols']))? "(`".implode("`,`",$settings['cols'])."`)":false;

if($cols == false)
    return false;

if(is_array($settings['vals']) && !empty($settings['vals'])) {
        foreach($settings['vals'] as $values) {
                $sql[]  =   "('".implode("','",$values)."')";
            }

        return $con->query("INSERT INTO {$table} {$cols} VALUES ".implode(",",$sql));

    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
// Include assets
include_once('interface.Database.php');
include_once('class.MySQLConn.php');
include_once('function.insert_into.php');

// Create instance and initialize connection
MySQLConn::SetConnection();

// create settings (you could get them from posts)
// You have to sanitize user input or as mentioned bind/prepare values    
$query["cols"]      =   array("naam","leeftijd","woonplaats");
$query["table"]     =   "gebruikers";
$query["vals"][]    =   array("Henk", 17, "Eindhoven");
$query["vals"][]    =   array("Ruud", 32, "Helmond");

insert_into($query);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very insightful. I'm pretty new to PHP so I'm earger to learn the possibilities.